# Can we use a While loop instead of a Do While

Tags: vb6

```
Open App.Path & "\employee.txt" For Input As #3

Do While (Not EOF(3))
    Input #3, strEmployeeRead
    lstEmployee.AddItem (strEmployeeRead)
Loop
Close #3
```

Can I replace the DO While (...) with a While Loop?

Comment: Depends, what are you trying to achieve and what actually happens?

Comment: There is no difference between `While blah ... Wend` and `Do While blah ... Loop`

Comment: `Do While` *is* a "While Loop". What actually do you want to do with this loop?

Answer (score 3):

In your case there is no need to have a `Do While` loop, you would get the same result using a `While` loop

```
While (Not EOF(3))
    ...
Wend
```

Usually you would opt for a `Do..While` loop over a `While` loop when you need to get at least 1 iteration *before* checking the state of your condition e.g.

```
Do
    ...
Loop While (Not EOF(3))
```

Comment: There is no `End While` in VB6. There is a `While/Wend` legacy construct.

Comment: @TomCollins the question was "*Can we use a While loop instead of a Do While*" - The answer to that question is "*yes*". The `Do..While` is more flexible than a `While` loop, however, I would be surprised if a `While` loop is considered "*deprecated*" and "*there for legacy purposes*" considering it's a fairly popular iteration mechanism in many languages.

Comment: Yes, the question was answered as asked. I added the comment so that the OP would know that in "VB6", While-Wend is officially "deprecated".  The comment wasn't directed to you James. I have moved my comment and placed it under the question instead.

Comment: why not use "do ... loop until eof(3)" ?

Comment: That fails if there are no records, but you can easily use `Do Until EOF(3) ... Loop` instead.

Comment: @TomCollins, `DO WHILE...LOOP` is not more flexible than `WHILE...WEND`; they are exact synonyms. I believe that `DO WHILE...LOOP` was introduced for symmetry when `DO...LOOP WHILE` was added in QuickBasic; MSBASIC used `WHILE...WEND` originally, before any Microsoft Basic had a post-condition loop.

Comment: Is it very much more flexible. The Do loop can be paired with "While" or "Until", and the condition can be checked at the "beginning" of the loop as well as the "end". So, in my book, that makes it 4 times more flexible.